# When can I go on another pickpocketing spree?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Having picked just … all the pockets, the towns of Skyrim are now well dry, so no more gems and rings and amulets for me.

But it stands to reason that these respawn, so when and how should I expect that to happen, if at all?

Moreover, if and when they do respawn, are townspeople's pockets affected by Prowler's Profit? (The Barenziah bonus)

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can determine, for named NPCs; [their inventory does not respawn](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/how-long-does-it-take-for-pickpocketed-people-to-respawn-items.250114726/) ([additional source](http://skyrimforums.org/sf/threads/shops-people-restock.15056/#post-190970)).

So if you pickpocket, say, Jarl Balgruuf; his inventory is static from when he is first loaded, and anything you pickpocket off him will never return. (*Insert region here*) Guards, however, are not *necessarily* static, and may have their inventories reset with the rest of the map cell they reside in if it has not been visited in 10 in-game days.

There may be some odd exception cases; particularly if a specific NPC is called upon by certain quests, it may generate a fresh version of that NPC complete with fresh inventory.

Comment: Can confirm this; stole a guard's armour, and three in-game weeks later he was still walking around completely naked except for his helmet and his loincloth.

Comment: I can confirm the same thing. Any NPC that respawns  (ie unnamed guards, etc) will respawn with fresh equipment, but that particular instance of a guard will never respawn more inventory.